# How does one specific a protocol in a function parameter?

Tags: ios, swift, function, parameters, protocols

I'm writing a factory class that is trying to work with custom protocol defined functions. The compiler throws an error, because I don't know how to add a protocol definition to a function parameter.

**Example:**

```
protocol MyCustomFunctions {
    func customFunction()
}

class MyVC: UIViewController, MyCustomFunctions {
    func customFunction() {}
}

class Factory {

    func createButton(specificVC: UIViewController) // need protocol here
    {
         specificVC.customFunction() // error thrown
    }
}
```

**How can one specific a protocol during a variable definition?**

Or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all ,convention says classes start with a Capital letter.

```
class MyVC: UIViewController, MyCustomFunctions {
    func customFunction() {}
}
```

Then what you need is the correct type in the argument

```
class factory: NSObject {

    func createButton(specificVC: MyVC) // you need a class that conforms to protocol here.
    {
         specificVC.customFunction() // no error anymore
    }
}
```

You have another option. You can simply promise in the argument that you won't disclose the full type of the object ,you will only say it's an opaque object that conforms to protocol.

```
class factory: NSObject {

    func createButton(specificVC: MyCustomFunctions) // you need a class that conforms to protocol here.
    {
         specificVC.customFunction() // no error anymore
    }
}
```

**BONUS:**

The way you could have reasoned about this and find an answer is this>

Error is thrown when I call `specificVC.customFunction()`...Hmmm...so this object can only run this function if it is of type that actually HAS the function. So let's take a look at the argument type - UIViewController - ..UIViewController certainly doesn't have this function. It's the MyVC or the Protocol.

Type safety in Swift is very strict. Just "follow the type flow" and you will be good.

Comment: And by default, if you don't have a specific reason, you don't need to inherit from NSObject in swift.  the Factory class should not inherit from anything.

Comment: Sorry, I'm crap at pseudo code. I actually follow both of your recommendations. My factory is actually more complicated than this example. I have multiple VC types coming in. I think your answer has pushed me into the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: I added a small bonus.